# Rebase branch from master to earlyer node on master

Tags: git, branch, rebase

Let's say i have the following graph:

```
   800      9ff
    v        v
----o--o--o--o--o--o <-master
              \
               o--o--o <-feature
```

And i want the following state after the command:

```
   800      9ff
    v        v
----o--o--o--o--o--o <-master
     \
      o--o--o <-feature
```

So how do i rebase backwards on the same branch? Could you please give an exact answer with the exact branchnames and 3-character-long hashes as specified?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gary Fixler found the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `rebase --onto` is for. While on `feature`, do this:

```
git rebase --onto 800 9ff
```

That moves the branch you're on (`feature`) onto 800 from 9ff.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do what you want.

```
git checkout 800
git cherry-pick 9ff..feature
git checkout -b newfeature
```

the resulting graph will look like

```
   800      9ff
    v        v
----o--o--o--o--o--o <-master
     \        \
      \        o--o--o <-feature
       \              \
        \      (The same commit)
         \           /
          \         /
           \       /
            o--o--o <-newfeature
```

Deleting the `feature` branch and renaming the `newfeature` branch will get you the graph you desire.

Comment: Of course with cherry picking this would work, but i wanted the rebase solution. Thanks though.